# Connecting the Radeon HD 5450

Tags: installation

I have never bought a graphics card before and am getting the hd 5450. This is probably a stupid question but the card does not come with anything but the card. I am ordering online and cant see it. Do i need to get a special cord to connect it to my monitor? i am only running one monitor so will the usual cord work.

Comment: Just to note: the 5450 is a pretty poor choice for playing the latest games, if you're getting it for that. A $30 card is really only going to let you use applications and play videos well.

Comment: So what do you recomend dont have a lot of cash and im just trying to upgrade my poor pc lol

Comment: I'd advise the 6850, which is about $135 at the moment :) I'll see if there's anything cheaper at the moment.

Comment: The 6750 is about $86, and should let you play modern games, but is much slower (1600 points vs. 2600 points on Passmark).

Comment: FYI the 5450 is 311 points on Passmark.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the website, the card has a VGA, HDMI, DVI and Display Port connector.

So pretty much any cable that can connect a graphics adapter to a monitor will work.

Comment: So the cord i use now will work?

Comment: I don't know what cord you're using right now.

Comment: @mgetts - Determine that when you get the card installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your PC has the relevant internal connector before you buy the card if it's an old machine, which will be PCI-Express. Before PCI-Express was AGP, which is incompatible. For connecting it up to your monitor, a DVI cable will suffice, or a VGA cable.